# Array not printing out correctly

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops

I've tried moving around my curly braces and just the entire structure of this program a bunch and can't seem to point out how to make this print out correctly. I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Game of Thrones|Action|HBO|50|Favorite
House of Cards|Drama|Netflix|50|Favorite
Huckabee|Bad Show|Fox News|25|Not favorite
Survivor|Reality|NBC|45|Not favorite
The Daily Show with Jon Stewart|Comedy|Comedy Central|30|Favorite
Louie|Comedy|FX|30|Favorite
Sports Center|Sports News|ESPN|60|Favorite
The Big Bang Theory|Comedy|CBS|30|Not favorite
Sesame Street|Educational|PBS|30|Favorite
Chopped|Food Show|Food Network|60|Favorite
```

I want my console to show this (minus the pipes) with a toString() that I have, which works perfectly fine, but it prints out with 10 copies of each show and I'm not sure what I can go about doing differently to fix this.

**Question: How can I make it so the console prints out exactly 1 copy of each show instead of 10?**

Driver Code:

```
   public class TVShowDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    TVShow[] tvShow = new TVShow[10];
    String tvName = "";
    String genre = "";
    String network = "";
    int runningTime = 0;
    String favorite = "";

    // reads in Shows.txt
    File tvShows = new File("./src/Shows.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(tvShows);

    // while there is a new line in the data, goes to the next one
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\|");

        // while there is a new attribute to read in on a given line, reads
        // data
        while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            tvName = lineScanner.next();
            genre = lineScanner.next();
            network = lineScanner.next();
            runningTime = lineScanner.nextInt();
            favorite = lineScanner.next();

            // creates a show
            for (int i = 0; i < tvShow.length; i++) {
                tvShow[i] = new TVShow(tvName, genre, network, runningTime,
                        favorite);
            }

        }

        // prints out shows
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(tvShow[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

}

TVShow Class:

```
public class TVShow {

    private String tvName;
    private String genre;
    private String network;
    private int runningTime;
    private String favorite;

    public TVShow(String tvName, String genre, String network, int runningTime, String favorite)
    {
        this.tvName = tvName;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.network = network;
        this.runningTime = runningTime;
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public String getTvName() {
        return tvName;
    }

    public void setTvName(String tvName) {
        this.tvName = tvName;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getNetwork() {
        return network;
    }

    public void setNetwork(String network) {
        this.network = network;
    }

    public int getRunningTime() {
        return runningTime;
    }

    public void setRunningTime(int runningTime) {
        this.runningTime = runningTime;
    }

    public String getFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(String favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "TV Show Name: " + tvName + ", Genre: " + genre + ", Network: " + network + ", Running Time: " + runningTime + " mins" + ", Favorite: " + favorite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: fix your indentation. (If the problem is not obvious after you do that, then carry on to step 2)

Comment: Can you add the `toString()` method from TVShow

Comment: ^ Or preferably, the whole `TVShow` class

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < tvShow.length; i++) {...` is wrong.  This filling the array with the same show information each time you read a new line.  Keep a counter of the current element you are up to an increment each time you read a new line from the file...

Comment: Another question: Why not use `string.split("\|")`

Comment: @Dando18 How would that differ from what I currently have?

Comment: @Jordan you could simplify all your line scanner logic into `String[] ary = fileContents.split("\|");`. and that would put all the values into an array for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
    // creates a show
    for (int i = 0; i < tvShow.length; i++) {
        tvShow[i] = new TVShow(tvName, genre, network, runningTime,
                              favorite);
    }
```

...is wrong.  Basically, each time you read a line from the file, you are re-filling the array with that show's details (sure you're making a new instance of `TVShow`, but it contains all the same details.

Instead, use a separate iteration value and increment each time you read a new line...

```
int currentLine = 0;
while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    if (currentLine < tvShow.length) {
        tvName = lineScanner.next();
        genre = lineScanner.next();
        network = lineScanner.next();
        runningTime = lineScanner.nextInt();
        favorite = lineScanner.next();

        tvShow[currentLine] = new TVShow(tvName, genre, network, runningTime,
                               favorite);
        currentLine++;
    } else {
        System.err.println("The array is full");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried doing a variation of this but I was writing within the bounds of some other curly braces and that really threw me off. Thanks @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in this piece:

```
// creates a show
for (int i = 0; i < tvShow.length; i++) {
    tvShow[i] = new TVShow(tvName, genre, network, runningTime,favorite);
}
```

You seem to be filling up the `tvShow` array each time with ten (which is the length of the array) copies of the same show.

A solution is to have a counter outside of your first while loop which you increment. Then use that counter to index into `tvShow`.

Alternatively, if you just want to print each show you could not bother to save them all in an array, create a TVShow variable outside of the while loops and reassign it.

So that would look like: 
`TVShow myShow; // outside of the first while loop loop`

`myShow = new TVShow(tvName, genre, network, runningTime,favorite); // where you were assigning into the array`